# Running node js server on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, web-applications, server

I have to build a twitter visualization app using node.js and I am following the tutorial http://blog.safe.com/2014/03/twitter-stream-api-map/

I followed the steps and now, when I run

```
node server.js
```

after being in the directory in which server.js is stored, Nothing happens.
And at `localhost:8081` the program does not work.

THe directory structure is

```
twitter --> node_modules, public, server.js
```

I used npm to install the required packages 
and used forever to run the server.

I have tried some fixes I found here and there on the net, nut nothing is working.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is the server.js :

```
    //Setup web server and socket
var twitter = require('twitter'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//Setup twitter stream api
var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXX'
}),
stream = null;

//Use the default port (for beanstalk) or default to 8081 locally
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081);

//Setup rotuing for app
app.use(express.static(__dir + '/public'));

//Create web sockets connection.
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on("start tweets", function() {

    if(stream === null) {
      //Connect to twitter stream passing in filter for entire world.
      twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-180,-90,180,90'}, function(stream) {
          stream.on('data', function(data) {
              // Does the JSON result have coordinates
              if (data.coordinates){
                if (data.coordinates !== null){
                  //If so then build up some nice json and send out to web sockets
                  var outputPoint = {"lat": data.coordinates.coordinates[0],"lng": data.coordinates.coordinates[1]};

                  socket.broadcast.emit("twitter-stream", outputPoint);

                  //Send out to web sockets channel.
                  socket.emit('twitter-stream', outputPoint);
                }
                else if(data.place){
                  if(data.place.bounding_box === 'Polygon'){
                    // Calculate the center of the bounding box for the tweet
                    var coord, _i, _len;
                    var centerLat = 0;
                    var centerLng = 0;

                    for (_i = 0, _len = coords.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                      coord = coords[_i];
                      centerLat += coord[0];
                      centerLng += coord[1];
                    }
                    centerLat = centerLat / coords.length;
                    centerLng = centerLng / coords.length;

                    // Build json object and broadcast it
                    var outputPoint = {"lat": centerLat,"lng": centerLng};
                    socket.broadcast.emit("twitter-stream", outputPoint);

                  }
                }
              }
              stream.on('limit', function(limitMessage) {
                return console.log(limitMessage);
              });

              stream.on('warning', function(warning) {
                return console.log(warning);
              });

              stream.on('disconnect', function(disconnectMessage) {
                return console.log(disconnectMessage);
              });
          });
      });
    }
  });

    // Emits signal to the client telling them that the
    // they are connected and can start receiving Tweets
    socket.emit("connected");
});
```

XXX fields I have filled fine after creatting twitter app.

Comment: I edited your question... never say things like "I'm in urgent need so please help"... nobody cares, and it makes people not want to answer your question.  Do you really believe that by saying you have an urgent problem that someone will answer your question more quickly than they would anyway?  No, that is not the case.  Please, ask focused specific questions here and you will get good answers.

Comment: When you run `node server.js ` what is the output?

Comment: @Novak007:  Try "nodejs server.js" instead of "node server.js"